# How to get min, max and average values in array of key=>value pairs in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, math, max, min

I have an array of variable size made of key value pairs; values are always floats, but keys are strings - for example:

```
$prices = array( 
    'name'   => 99.23
    'abc'    => 239.2,
    'xyz'    => 102.452,
    'foobar' => 152,
    'barfoo' => 159.2394
    ...
)
```

I need to get at least three values, but that also depends on the size of the array.
For example, if the array is made of 6 keys, I'd like to get the two lowest ones, the two highest ones and the remainder two ones (which should fall in the middle). If 7 keys perhaps the 2 lowest, 2 highest and the middle 3. If 8, maybe 3-2-3...

I'm not sure how to create a pattern, but ideally should be as evenly distributed as possible, or even better if it could take in consideration prices that are a bit too high or too low in the average remainder values (and rather push these in the highest or lowest groups respectively).

I can't know in advance the number of keys in array (there could be even just 1 up to a dozen) nor the numerical ranges in their values (always a positive float or integer).
I need to retain the keys in each group as I will need to use them later.

I know there are min() and max() but those are meant for lists of numbers not key-value pairs.

Ideally I would like to get something like this:

```
$lowest = array(
    'name'   => 99.23
    'xyz'    => 102.452
);

$highest = array(
    'abc'    => 239.2,
    'barfoo' => 159.2394
);

$average = array(
    'foobar' => 152,
);
```

Eventually I only need to retain the keys for use later, from these 3 arrays above. (The example above assumes 5 keys in array, which may vary).

Comment: http://php.net/asort, then http://php.net/array_slice however you like it. You'll have to give a more concrete goal if you need more concrete help.

Comment: Well, again, `array_slice` makes this trivial by slicing `0,2`, `-2` and `2,-2`. However, since you don't seem to be sure that that's what you want, it's hard to give you concrete advice.

Comment: I'm just reading the docs, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this.

```
$prices = array( 
    'abc' => 239.2,
    'xyz' => 102.452,
    'foobar' => 152,
    'barfoo' => 159.2394,
    'be' => 26.234,
    'dfi' => 789.233
    );

$len1 = ceil(count($prices)/3);    //calculate boundary array length
$len2 = count($prices) - 2*$len1;  //calculate middle array length

sort($prices);  //sorting array

$array1 = array_slice($prices,0,$len1);   //get first array (min)
$array2 = array_slice($prices,$len1,$len2);   //get second array (middle)
$array3 = array_slice($prices,$len1+$len2,$len1);   //get third array (max)
```

Comment: thanks Sampath - with your answer and deceze comment, I figured out I could have used sort for this - more precisely asort, as I needed to preserve my keys (in your example above you mention sort, which throws the array keys away). I also modified how the array are built but yours provided a good hint, thank you